# ANTLR4 - parsing `any string` without consuming the whole input

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, antlr4, lexer

I am trying to parse the following text format:

```
<identifier> {
    <identifier> : <any-text-without-white-space-or-new-line> : <identifier>
    <identifier> : <identifier>.<identifier>
}
```

**For example:**

```
john {
    name : JohnJohnson.12.453.643-USA[NewYork] : default
    reference : something.else
}
```

I have created the following grammar:

```
SPACE          : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
LEFT_BRACE     : '{';
RIGHT_BRACE    : '}';
COLON          : ':';
DOT            : '.';
ID             : [a-z]+
ANY            : ~(' '|'\t'|'\r'|'\n')+;

outer          : ID LEFT_BRACE inner_first inner_second RIGHT_BRACE EOF;
inner_first    : ID COLON (ANY | ID) COLON ID;
inner_second   : ID COLON ID DOT ID;
```

The problem in this grammer is that `<identifier>.<identifier>` in the input of the second line is recognized as

```
ANY
```

and not as

```
ID DOT ID
```

I can fix this if I change the definition of `ANY` to:

```
ANY            : ~(' '|'\t'|'\r'|'\n'|'.')+;
```

But this means that the `.` symbol cannot be part anymore of the arbitrary text in the first line.

This seems like a chicken/egg problem. Is this solvable?

(FWIW, I am reading the great book `The Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference` which I bought some time ago, but I have not find a solution yet.)

Answer (score 0):

You could always have the lexer rule tokenize the minimum amount and have some parser rules, instead of lexer rules, to represent the combination of whatever your want. Let's say:

```
my_desired_seq     : NON_WS_CRLF_DOT_SEQ  DOT NON_WS_CRLF_DOT_SEQ  ;
NON_WS_CRLF_DOT_SEQ      : ~(' '|'\t'|'\r'|'\n'|'.')+;
```

and other part of the grammar use the parser rule instead:

```
inner_second   : ID COLON my_desired_seq;
```